# Query Compare to Find Matches

Tags: ms-access

I have two queries in MS Access.  One has a field labeled `"Assembly"` and the other query has it's field labeled `"Assemblies"`.

I need to compare the two queries (both with only the one column) and find out from the query with the `"Assemblies"` column which entries MATCH the other query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the matching records, a simple `inner join` will suffice here, e.g.:

```sql
select * from query1 inner join query2 on query1.assembly = query2.assemblies
```

Rename `query1` & `query2` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac - I'll give it a try

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!